# Classification of elements in mapping class groups

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

Recently I start learning mapping class group. The Nielsen-Thurston classification says that each element in mapping class group $Mod(S_{g,n}),g,n\geq 0$ is periodic, reducible, or pseudo-Anosov. Take any element in $Mod(S_{g,n})$, how to determine the element is in which one of the cases?

Comment: Do you want an algorithm or would you be content with something more conceptual?   As far as I know there aren't any super-fast algorithms but there's plenty of heuristic tools that get you nice places.

Comment: Any references for the tools you mentioned?

Comment: see also flipper by Mark Bell:
http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1410.1358
https://bitbucket.org/Mark_Bell/flipper/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An effective algorithm can be found in

```
 Mladen Bestvina and Michael Handel. Train-tracks for surface homeomorphisms. Topology, vol. 34 (1995), no. 1, pp. 109–140
```

This has been implemented by Peter Brinkman in Xtrain (which you can get via computop.org).

Comment: @Yu-ChanChang - If you like this answer, you should accept it (by clicking on the "check" mark.)

Comment: @SamNead Does this person still exist?